# POM vs PageFactory

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, page-objects, pom, page-factory

I'm starting my career as a QA Automation Engineer coming from a Jr dev background. I noticed that there are two main design patterns for Selenium, POM and PageFactory.

- Which is the preferred design pattern to use in best practice?
- Also, there are several ways of finding an HTML element. Which one tends to be the best practice rule of finding an element? Is it ID?

As for Page Factory, my understanding is that for each webpage, you create a class representation of said webpage, and within the class, you create methods that act upon the webelements. You then will have different test classes that do the actual testing. Please correct or confirm my understanding.

Comment: have you tried spending at least 2 minutes with google before asking this question?

Comment: No, I decided to type two paragraphs on the matter for the hell of it.

Comment: Here is an answer on first part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866113/what-is-the-differnce-between-page-object-model-and-page-factory-in-selenium

Comment: Thanks, it seems like they are identical/doing the same thing. The only difference looks like that in Page Factory (like the poster mentioned) that it is initializing the elements to be used. So, I'm guessing usually Page Factory is mostly used, or depending on the situation?

Comment: Yes, PageFactory is just POM + easy way of initializing elements. I cant think of any case where you would not use PF as it allows you to write less code/makes code less complex.

Comment: Don't ask two questions in one. Best ways to find elements is answered here already: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27978/what-makes-a-good-selenium-locator

Comment: Also it is customary to wait at least 24 hours before accepting the answer, to allow people from other time zones to contribute: help you, and earn XP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the Page Factory is an extension of the Page Object Model. [This  Selenium documentation page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) describes with examples what the Factory adds.

> If you use the PageFactory, you can assume that the fields are
>   initialised. If you don't use the PageFactory, then
>   NullPointerExceptions will be thrown if you make the assumption that
>   the fields are already initialised.

Guess that is the biggest win.

Personally I couldn't really care for the PageFactory, just adds magic and makes stuff more complex for new developers/testers.

> Within your web app's UI there are areas that your tests interact
>   with. A Page Object simply models these as objects within the test
>   code. This reduces the amount of duplicated code and means that if the
>   UI changes, the fix need only be applied in one place.
>
> Read more [here...](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)

I do love the Page Objects because it lowers maintenance and makes the tests more readable.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was assuming. From my understanding, the main significant difference is that the elements are already initialized if a page factory design pattern is being used. Hence the    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); method call. I'm just curious as to learning what is most used in the automation field as a design pattern, since I'll be starting off my career in it pretty soon. :)

Do you yourself typically use Page Objects or Page Factory typically?

Comment: Based on that fact that the factory extends the object-model. I would guess the object-model must be more popular. You can always later switch to the factory pattern. Not using the object-model seems unacceptable for my projects, not using the factory...

Comment: Makes sense. It would also seem logically, that if you have a large webpage and have a bunch of elements and are using Page Factory, all those elements would be initialized within the constructor. Thus, slowing down the  automation software requiring linear complexity time to the amount of elements (Big O N).

Comment: Also we write our tests in JavaScript and not Java. I think the JavaScript versions of Selenium do not even have a PageFactory replacement.

Comment: No, elements are not initialised, please read the documentation: "WebElements are evaluated lazily. That is, if you never use a WebElement field in a PageObject, there will never be a call to "findElement" for it."

Comment: Interesting, so the PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); method would know if a WebElement is being used, and if it isn't it won't be initialized?

Comment: it will be initialized in a sense that variable will have assigned value, but not in a sense that variable will hold actual webelement. That happens only when interacting with it.

Comment: I see. Object creation happens once it's detected to being used at runtime.

Comment: @chris It's called lazy loading or lazy initialization. It's lazy because unless you interact with it it won't be initialized, i.e., it won't search for matching element in HTML.

Comment: @dzieciou Makes perfect sense. Also, thanks for all your answers everyone, this helped.