# find_elements_by_xpath issue!

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I'm trying to complete the basic python Selenium demo (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) but I'm attempting to do that same procedure on https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/. However, it seems to be returning an empty list/it can't find the element. I tried to use the class_name but that also gave me an error because the class name has a space in it.

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("typeahead tt-hint")
elem2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="main_content"]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/span/input[1]')
```

Also, when doing the tutorial and trying the find_elements command on the different options
`<input id="id-search-field" name="q" type="search" role="textbox" class="search-field" placeholder="Search" value="" tabindex="1">`
I don't quite understand why I seemed to get a type 
`<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>`if I used `elem = driver.find_element_by_name('q')` and a `<type 'list'>` if I used anything else (xpath, id, class_name, etc).

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please tell which element on https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ you are trying to locate? I don't see any element with `class_name=typeahead` or with `id=main_content`. Also, you can try locating with just `class=typeahead` instead of `typeahead tt-hint`.

To your second question, you get WebElement when you use `find_element` and a list when you use `find_elements`.

Comment: Oh the element/elements issue makes sense, thanks so much! I was trying to locate the text box but I think that I may have been attempting to use to wrong tag/id? Anyway, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, regarding your question about the return types of the "find" commands, it's quite straightforward:

- `find_element_by_*()` methods return a [`WebElement` instance](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) - or, in other words, a single element
- `find_elements_by_*()` methods return a list of `WebElement` instances - or, on other words, a list of elements

---

Now, let's look at what specific problems you have.

I am assuming you are working with [this search page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/search/?term=) as I do see the text box you are talking about on this page. Let's look at this attempt you had to find the text box:

> `elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("typeahead tt-hint")`

First of all, you need to use `find_element_by_class_name()` as you are looking for a single element only. Also, this locator *only accept single class values* - so, you could use either `driver.find_element_by_class_name("typeahead")`, or `driver.find_element_by_class_name("tt-hint")`.

If you need to check both of the class values, you could use a CSS selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".typeahead.tt-hint")
```

And, as we are looking for an `input` element, we could add the tag name check here as well:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.typeahead.tt-hint")
```

But, as this element has an `id` element, you should just use "find element by id" strategy:

```
search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("search_term")
search_box.send_keys("my search query")
```

Make sure to look over this thread to get a better idea when to use what locator:

- [What makes a good selenium locator?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/27978/5574)